# How can I debug my recursive function that's causing stack overflow error?

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-c++

The problem I'm trying to solve is KR2 exercise 1-22; 'write a program to "fold" long input lines into two or more shorter lines after the last non-blank character that occurs before the n-th column of input. Make sure your program does something intelligent with very long lines, and if there are no blanks or tabs before the specified column'.

I've attempted to do with a recursive function which just gets stuck.

Example of erroneous behavior:
hello world << input
output >>
hell
o wo
o wo
o wo
o wo
....
...
Expected behavior:
hello world << input
output >>
hell
o wo
rld

Second example of erroneous behavior:
h e llo world << input
output >>
h e
 llo
llo
 llo
llo
 llo
llo
....
...
Secondary expected behavior:
h e llo world << input
output >>
h e
 llo
 wor
ld

See code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PAGEWIDTH 5
#define MAXLINE 1000

int getline(char line[], int maxline);
void fold(char line[], int start);

/* "fold" long input lines into two or more shorter lines after
  the last non-blnk character that occurs before the n-th
  column of input */
int main()
{
    int len;                /* current line length*/
    char line[MAXLINE];     /* current input lne*/

    while ((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
        if (len > PAGEWIDTH)
            fold(line, 0);
    return 0;
}

/* getline : read a line into s, return length */
int getline(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i;

    c = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < lim - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';

    return i;
}

void fold(char line[], int start)
{
    int i, lstnb;
    i = lstnb = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < PAGEWIDTH-1 && line[start + i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        if (line[start + i] != ' ')
            lstnb = i;
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= lstnb; ++i)
        putchar(line[start + i]);

    putchar('\n');
    if(line[lstnb + 1] != '\0')
        fold(line, lstnb + 1);
}
```

Comment: I'd start using a debugger. But why do you want to do it recursively instead of with a loop?

Comment: It felt more intuitive to approach it this way. I plan to rewrite it to work iteratively if I can't figure out the current issue. I've made use of print statements and the debugger although I'm still confused. Using the debugger and inspecting variable "start" on the initial call of function fold, value is 0. On the subsequent, it's -129496704, instead of 4 as expected for the given first example "hello world" input. Printing the argument (start) that is provided to fold does show 4 though. I think compiler optimisations may be the reason for difference as things still work up to a point.

Comment: Things appear to go wrong in the following for loop:                                                                                    
 `for (i = 0; i < PAGEWIDTH-1 && line[start + i] != '\0'; ++i) {
  if (line[start + i] != ' ')
   lstnb = i;`

Comment: Hint: the problem is in the last two lines of the `fold` function. Hint 2: consider what `lstnb` actually represents.

Comment: Hint 3 : you are abusing recursion here. This can be very easily transformed into a loop and maybe then you'll find the bug as well.

Comment: Do you want us to tell you what the fix is? Or just guide you to the answer?

Comment: Recursion can be a great way to solve problems; but when you find yourself writing loops within your recursive function definitions, or recursive function definitions that return `void`, you should wonder if you are on the right track. BTW, your function definition is tail-recursive; C does not guarantee tail-call elimination, but GCC _does_ support it. I don't know that any other C compilers do this optimization, though, and I seriously doubt that MSVC does.

Comment: @Jabberwocky thanks, those hints really helped. I take it in your comment that I am "abusing recursion" you are alluding to 'ex nihilo' clarifications on why my recursion approach isn't ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

good question. First, I think that a recursive solution isn't ideal here. I got it working for the inputs you gave, but considering how small `PAGEWIDTH` is, you'll likely run into issues with larger inputs. Using a loop would make your life easier and result in a more reliable function.

That said, your issue lies in the recursive call you make in the `fold()` function, you are providing the wrong start index. This means you don't move forward in the line with each call. Also, you don't clearly define a base case (i.e. when to end the recursion). You can do this by modifying your for loop conditions or passing the string length (n) to the function and checking whether start > n.

Checking base case and the recursive call is always a good place to start when debugging recursive functions. This is normally where my issues come from and it's really easy to assume you did them correctly and overlook them while debugging.

I'm not sure what you are looking for in terms of an answer, but if those suggestions don't get you any closer, I pasted a fix in a pastebin [here](https://pastebin.com/tVehCFRT). I didn't post it here in case you wanted to solve it on your own.

Hope that works, let me know if there's something I missed.